# How do skip the DB deploy task in Sitecore Install Framework

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I'm trying to install a load balanced CM pair. There are 2 CMs. I thought the install script automatically skips the DB deploy task if the DBs are installed, but doesn't look like. When I install the first CM, everything is fine. Then for the second one, I want to skip the DB Deploy task. I looked in the JSON config, and it's all wrapped in the InstallWDP task. How do you skip the individual DB deploy task? I assume this will be an issue for CD installs, as well, right?

To be more specific, I want to skip it during the execution, i.e. when calling `Install-SitecoreConfiguration` - as I understand it, I should be able to pass in a parameter called `Skip`

Comment: Are you getting any error when installing the second CM? I don't think it is possible to skip the database deploy because like you said it's all wrapped in the `InstallWDP` task. `InstallWDP` invokes the *Microsoft Web Deploy V3* by passing arguments to msbuild.exe.

Comment: Yes - essentially, when you install CM first, the contained property set back to 'false' for those databases. Then when the CD is being installed, it tries to do something with the user, and it fails because of that. If I go into the DB, and then set the contained property back, it works. Possibly in CI build I can add that task, but why does a CD need to do anything with the DB for installation?

Answer (score 10):

Web deploy supports the ability to skip elements of a manifest using the "skip directive".

SIF maps the arguments from the `json` SIF config to the web deploy command, so you need to add:

```
"Skip": [
          { "ObjectName": "dbDacFx" },
          { "ObjectName": "dbFullSql" }
        ],
```

[image: SIF config sample showing "Skip" statement in use with MSDeploy]